# Shrinkwrap modifier onto displaced surface

Tags: displacement, shrinkwrap

I am trying to shrinkwrap an element onto a displaced plane. The displacement on the plane is created by inserting a texture into the Displacement input socket of the Material Output node for the material, and adding a Subsurf modifier with the Adaptive option turned on, as opposed to using the Displace modifier.

[image: before shrinkwrap]

When I apply the shrinkwrap modifier in mode Project, the yellow element does project to the plane but it doesn't wrap around its curves. It just sits flat on the plane, as if it hadn't been displaced.

[image: after shrinkwrap]

I have tried turning the yellow curve into a mesh and subdividing with the same result.

But if I displace the plane with a Displace modifier instead, the yellow line does wrap around correctly. But as I am doing this on a very large terrain, I have to subdivide it a lot, and it slows down everything.

My question is, is there no way to use adaptive displacement and the shrinkwrap modifier at the same time ? Is the geometry not trully displaced or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks !

Comment: Material based displacement is calculated at render time only can't be used elsewhere, if you want true displacement use the modifier.

Comment: Thanks Duarte, I suspected that was the case, but since it complicates my project so much I was hoping for a one of those "crazy" solutions sometimes we find here. Thanks ! Obrigado !

Comment: Either separate your large terrain into small chunks across several scenes, or if this is a one-time thing add the modifier shrink wrap the ribbon, apply the modifier and return everything to the previous form with material based displace. Otherwise you can keep the displacement modifier low res on the viewport only so it wont weight down